# html images in Atom editor

Tags: html, css, image, atom-editor

I know this is a ridiculous question but I can't get these images to show.  Please help I'm using Atom

```
<body>
    <div class="top-container">
      <img src="images/cloud.png>" alt="cloud-img">
      <h1>I'm Paul</h1>
      <p>A Programer.</p>
      <img src="images/cloud.png>" alt="cloud-img">
      <img src="images/mountain.png>" alt="mountain-img">
    </div>**strong text**
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `cloud.png` instead of `cloud.png>`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the enclosing tag from images

```
    <div class="top-container">
      <img src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
      <h1>I'm Paul</h1>emphasized text
      <p>A Programer.</p>
      <img src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
      <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
    </div>
```